# Working with fragment class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello i want to working with fragment class.
in this code what to write???
in the myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(???????);

```
public class Tozihat extends Fragment{

DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tozihat, container, false);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();

    return view;

}
```

}

Comment: question totally not clear )) if you want to pass activity context then `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getActivity(); as Context if it is Fragment

```
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `Activity's Context`. So in `Fragment` you have to get is using `getActivity()`.

So pass it as follows

```
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
```